# От сумы, да от тюрьмы не зарекайся - что за сума?

Tags: пословицы

Я всю жизнь считал, что это сума с деньгами, то есть нежданное богатство, а вот народ в интернете считает, что эта сума как-то относится к нищенству.

Comment: Я тоже! всю жизнь я думал что это имеется ввиду что ни от богатства ни от бед не зарейкайся - а получается - только от бед )))

Comment: If you like the answer, then you probably like this question, too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Это сума, которую носит нищий попрошайка, и собирает в неё подаяние.

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/сума](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0)

> 2 перен. символ нищеты, нищенства, банкротства ◆ Разве стечение бед не
>   может и самого трудолюбивого довести до сумы? Н. М. Карамзин, «Письма
>   русского путешественника», 1793 г...  ◆ В пять лет не устроишь нового
>   хозяйства, а в пять-то годов можно и до сумы дойти… П. И.
>   Мельников-Печерский, «На горах», 1875—1881 г...

https://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=39515

> ... Ходить с сумой, собирать подаяние. Пустить кого с сумою, разорить
>   впух...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97337/discussion-on-answer-by-dimitri-vulis---------).

Comment: An example from Pushkin:      

  "Не дай мне Бог сойти с ума.        
  Нет, легче посох и сума..."

Comment: Я бы добавил, что подаяние чаще всего было не денежное, а продуктами, поэтому сума была насущной необходимостью.